# why update ignore sql query have an impact on replication?

Tags: mysql, sql, replication, database-replication

I have a trouble understanding why update ignore sql query would have an impact on replication? Could someone explain a way that I could understand instead of pointing out that it is unsafe for statement-based replication..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is right on the help page for the UPDATE statement

> UPDATE IGNORE statements, including those having an ORDER BY clause, are flagged as unsafe for
>   statement-based replication. (This is because the order in which the
>   rows are updated determines which rows are ignored.) With this change,
>   such statements produce a warning in the log when using
>   statement-based mode and are logged using the row-based format when
>   using MIXED mode. (Bug #11758262, Bug #50439) See Section 18.2.1.3,
>   “Determination of Safe and Unsafe Statements in Binary Logging”, for more information.

Seems clear to me -- what exactly is your question?

(ref http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html)

Comment: thanks not really a expert in db by any means. I guess i need to start venturing more than what i do at my day job..